# Will the future be human brains in robots?

Tags: robots, humanoid

Theoretically a human brain integrated into a robot body could have the longest lifespan and be the most efficient in the work force. Disease would be minimal. But is it in the realms of possibility?

You don't have to answer all the questions.

1. Could you still have a nervous system through electric impulses imitating the sense of touch?
2. How would you nourish your brain to sustain life if you don't have a stomach?
3. Procreation would have to be done prior to becoming a human robot, as this would simply not be possible.
4. What would the new estimated lifespan be?
5. A bionic heart would be the most optimal, but would this be possible?

If disease became rampant and technology is very advanced you never know what is in the realms of possibility.

Comment: "you never know what is in the realm of possibility." I think this shows why this isn't a good question, nobody really knows and the question is very broad and open ended.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Comment: I think this may make a good series of questions- it may even give birth to a new tag!

Comment: Where exactly is a robot superior? There is no robot which can stay operative for 80+years like a human body can do.

Comment: Human brains in robots is an evolutionary dead end, if there is no way that they can subsequently reproduce.

Comment: seeing ten brains swimming inside a fish tank becomes a thing during recession

Comment: The entire [Ghost In The Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell) franchise revolves around the concept of human brains in robot bodies. In brief your question lacks imagination. 1) Can electrical impulses do the job of biological nerves? Yes, we are doing that **today** already. 2) How can you nourish your brain if you do not have a stomach? By skipping that whole troublesome digestive tract and provide the brain with the nutrients that a DT normally produce. 3) We have been able to do human in vitro procreation for decades. What we do not yet have is in vitro **gestation**.

Comment: (cont.) ...but that issue does not require much suspension of disbelief. 4) For as long that you as an author decide. Nothing suggests we will not be able to stop brain aging. 5) We already today have non-biological hearts. There are persons that do not have a pulse, but instead a uniform and smooth flow of blood thanks you a turbine-like blood pump that replaces their heart.  Also: you can never prove a negative, so you could never prove that human cyborgs are **not** possible. The question is rather: is this a credible concept, yes or no? None of your points discredit that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

This scheme wouldn't work for multiple reasons, but I will cite just one:

Brain cannot work as an isolated organ, even assuming you can give enough nutrients to keep it healthy and functioning (this could be done, in a reasonable future) and are able to plug into it input/outputs to the robotic body (this also, with a certain difficulty, mainly due to needed number of nanotransducers, is thinkable) what it will stop you is the brain works in a complex system where neurotransmitters are generated in places very far from it.

As an example: it seems a fundamental impulse for long term memorization is a systemic (blood-stream) neurotransmitter produced by cardiac ganglia; other parts of "reward system", essential for learning, are connected to various parts of our body, including adrenal and intestine ganglia.

Comment: May I know reason for downvoting?

Comment: I do not know why you were downvoted, but I upvoted you again - I am sure you are right.

Comment: Good answer ZioByte. Althogh i disagree with the not possible aspect of it, i like to see it as we are not near scientifically evolved yet.